# Chain Promises in Play Framework Using Java

Tags: java, playframework, reactive-programming

I have a controller action where I need to call 3rd party web services.

My problem is that I am not calling one web service. I need to chain between 4 to 5 web services. Each web service I call returns a JSON object which I need to process and based on some logic I decide to either call another web service (from the 4 web services) or return a response to the caller. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
 public static Promise<Result> accounts(){
    return WS.url("url1").get().map(response1 -> {
        JsonNode mynode = response1.asJson();

        if (mynode.get("status").asInt()==200){
            Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise = WS.url("url2").get().map(response2->{
                    return response2.asJson();
            });
        }

        return ok(mynode);
        }); 
}
```

Now, from the documentation, I think that what I need is to chain promises where each web service call is a promise. But I am not sure how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're calling it ***Reactive Composition*** and it's done like this ->

```
public static Promise<Result> reactiveCombo() {
    Promise<WSResponse> promise1 = WS.url("url1").get();
    Promise<WSResponse> promise2 = WS.url("url2").get();
    Promise<WSResponse> promise3 = WS.url("url3").get();

    return promise1.flatMap(response1 -> {
        final JsonNode json1 = response1.asJson();
        if (!json1.has("someField")) {
            return Promise.promise(() -> badRequest());
        }
        return promise2.flatMap(response2 -> {
            final JsonNode json2 = response2.asJson();
            if (json1.get("someField").asText().equals(json2.get("someField").asText())) {
                return Promise.promise(() -> badRequest());
            }
            return promise3.map(response3 -> {
                final JsonNode json3 = response3.asJson();
                if (json3.get("boolField").asBoolean()) {
                    return badRequest();
                }
                return ok();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

For large # of calls you can use `Promise.sequence()` and get 'creative':

```
private static Promise<JsonNode> getPromise(String url, Predicate<JsonNode> predicate) {
    return WS.url(url).get().map(response -> {
        JsonNode json = response.asJson();           
        if (predicate.negate().test(json)) {
            throw new Exception("BUMMER!");
        }
        return json;
    });
}

public static Promise<Result> reactiveCombo(List<String> urls) {
    List<Promise<JsonNode>> promises = new ArrayList<Promise<JsonNode>>(urls.size());
    Predicate<String> predURL = p -> p.contains("goodApi");
    Predicate<JsonNode> pred1 = p -> p.has("boolField") && p.get("boolField").asBoolean();
    Predicate<JsonNode> pred2 = p -> p.has("someField");

    urls.forEach(url -> {
        Promise<JsonNode> promise = predURL.test(url) ? getPromise(url, pred1) : getPromise(url, pred2);           
        promises.add(promise);
    });

    return Promise.sequence(promises).map(results -> ok()).recover(t -> badRequest());
}
```

Additional details + docudrama:

[Go Reactive with Java 8 & Play Framework](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-java8-play) (old but still educative)

[JavaWS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS)

Comment: OK this works like a charm.  However, the code looks ugly. I am talking to a DB server to perform some CRUD operations. It is clear to me that the DB REST APIs could be improved a lot to reduce the number of calls and also to provide safe transaction operations. But it is not something I can do. For example in one scenario I end up calling 10  REST APIs. SO any suggestions how I can improve the code

Comment: Well, you could, for example put your URLs in an array, iterate over it and for each URL you create a `Promise<T>` that you add to a `List<Promise<T>> promisesList`. Then you can use `Promise.sequence(primisesList).map((List<T> resultList) -> {...});`. That would reduce the nesting quite a bit.

Comment: This might help. I hope whoever ends up maintaining this code in the future does not know where I live :)

Comment: Heh, come on... It's not THAT bad.

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion to flatten this structure for any number of Promises.
First create a class:

```
public static class ChainedWebService {
    public final Optional<ChainedWebService> next;

    public final WSRequestHolder wsResponsePromise;
    private final F.Predicate<JsonNode> predicate;

    public ChainedWebService(String url, Optional<ChainedWebService> next, F.Predicate<JsonNode> predicate) {
        this.next = next;
        this.wsResponsePromise = WS.url(url);
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public F.Promise<Result> processChain() {
        return wsResponsePromise.get().flatMap(new F.Function<WSResponse, F.Promise<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> apply(WSResponse wsResponse) throws Throwable {
                if (!predicate.test(wsResponse.asJson())) {
                    return F.Promise.pure(badRequest());
                }

                if (!next.isPresent()) {
                    return F.Promise.pure(ok());
                }

                return next.get().processChain();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> reactiveCombo() {
    ChainedWebService chainedWebService3 = new ChainedWebService(
            "url3",
            Optional.<ChainedWebService>empty(),
            jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("boolField").asBoolean()
    );

    ChainedWebService chainedWebService2 = new ChainedWebService(
            "url2",
            Optional.of(chainedWebService3),
            jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("someField").asText().equals(jsonNode.get("someField").asText()));

    ChainedWebService chainedWebService1 = new ChainedWebService(
            "url1",
            Optional.of(chainedWebService2),
            jsonNode -> jsonNode.has("someField")
    );

    return chainedWebService1.processChain();
}
```

You can implement some basic builder to make the building process more reasonable.

Hope thats help!

Comment: Interesting approach, but you have `Promise.sequence()` exactly for this. Plus, you're really risking to fill-up the stack with this solution.

Comment: @sebster using `Promise.sequence()` will mean executing all the requests, which is not necessary in this case.